# Mouseout detect the new div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseout

When I mouseover a div i do some stuff and put a modal window next to the said div. When I mouse away I need to hide the modal. The problem is when I move my mouse to the modal it disappears because i am no longer mousing over the original div.

Is there a way to detect what div I am mousing over in the mouseout event? Whats the cleanest way to not hide the modal div?

Comment: Can you post and example jsfiddle with what you have already maybe? Try and help from there?

Comment: you open a modal on mouseover? or is it more like a tooltip? essentially if there is not space between the modal and the hover trigger then you just say when hovered over the trigger and modal show modal

Answer (score 4):

Try to put your modal window inside "mouseovered" div.

It should do the trick

---

EDIT:

Since you can't put the modal window inside you can try something "tricky".

```
var timerFade;
$(function(){
    $(".element").mouseout(function(){
        timerFade = setTimeout(500,function(){
            // make the modal disappear
        });
    });
    $("#modalWindow").mouseover(function(){
        clearTimeout(timerFade);
    });
    $(".element").mouseover(function(){
        timerFade = setTimeout(500,function(){
            clearTimeout(timerFade);
        });
        // if modal is hidden, show it or move from another
            // element whith same behavior
    });

});
```

Assuming that the div you want to over on has class "element" and modal window has id "modalWindow".

It means that you hide the modal window at a set timeout and you clear it when you rollover on th modal win or on the element again

Just an idea ^^

[Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/YuSEF/)

Comment: Can't the html on the outside breaks the modal if the modal is a child. But +1 anyways

Comment: obviously you should adapt your css. If you put it absolutely should be fair. Btw I can be more specific if you put your code or an example code like your.

Comment: Its kind of hard to reproduce or explain but one is is the parent are draggable (jquery ui) and one item in the modal is a video which doesn't click correctly because of it. I put it in an iframe but it feels like a hack. Also dragging of the modal would drag the parent which is awkward (bc its detached). I also had to change CSS so no rules collide. Its messy and I don't want to go through with it on this new thing

Comment: I was thinking of doing that but than i notice the mouseover happens before mouseout!

Comment: for reference, i've written an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/YuSEF/). I didn't understand what you meant ^^

Answer (score 3):

If you can surround both of the div's with another div.

```
<div id="outter">
  <div id="inner">
    ....some stuff
  </div>
  <div id="modal">
    ...some stuff
  </div>
</div>
```

set the mouseover to the inner, and the mouseout to the outter.

Comment: +1 but actually put **mouseenter** and **mouseleave** (AKA `.hover()`) to `.outer`

Comment: Good idea but the html on the outside breaks the modal if the modal is a child. +1 anyways

Comment: I cant use this either (see comment on other answer) but i have an idea to solve this

Answer (score 0):

Use the event relatedTarget duh :(. It would have really helped if ANYONE said that :(